# Where can I download the offline installer of Google chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, download

Where can I download the offline installer of Google chrome?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?standalone=1

or

http://dl.google.com/chrome/install/154.36/chrome_installer.exe

Answer (score 1):

You can get offline installers for the latest and past versions (all the way back to the first release) of Chrome from [FileHippo](http://www.filehippo.com/download_google_chrome/).

The installers from the Google page pack a Google Update installer and the Chrome installer together. When you run it, it extracts the two and runs them. The FileHippo copy is only the extracted Chrome installer (including the Google digital signature).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Mac OS Mojave in the Firefox browser. Go to

```
https://www.google.com/chrome/thank-you.html?standalone=1&statcb=0&installdataindex=empty&defaultbrowser=0#
```

and then click on

"download Chrome manually"

It should download the latest googlechrome.dmg

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, the direct link seems to be:

```
https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/GGRO/googlechrome.dmg
```